# Application Default Credentials not available - localhost project

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to make a call to Google Speech API using the library method (I don't want to make a direct call to an endpoint) and I get this error:

> The Application Default Credentials are not available.
>   They are available if running in Google Compute Engine.
>   Otherwise, the environment variable *GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS*
>   must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials.

I have already downloaded the JSON credentials file from my service account and defined the *GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS* environment variable pointing to it.

I have also created this *GCLOUD_PROJECT* variable which is set to the "*project_id*" field in my JSON file.

I am not providing any extra authentication when using the library method - but this has worked in another local environment which probably had some other configuration that I am missing.

```
 var speech = SpeechClient.Create();
            var response = speech.Recognize(new RecognitionConfig()
            {
                Encoding = RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Linear16,

                LanguageCode = languageCode,
            }, RecognitionAudio.FromFile(file));
```

The authentication file is of type service account, if that helps.

```
"type": "service_account",
```

Answer (score 4):

Setting the environment variable worked for me. Use the code:

```
System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", <<path>>);
```

You need to use path of json file that you get from Google Api page.

Answer (score 0):

I found that your code is similar to code in this repo [dotnet-docs-samples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples.git) So I tried to replicate what you describe in a GCP Compute Engine instance.

```
$ curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > microsoft.gpg
$ sudo mv microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.0.2
$ git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples.git
$ cd dotnet-docs-samples/speech/api/QuickStart/


$ dotnet run
```

At this point the environment was set, except for the variables. So predictably `dotnet run` command failed with an error.

```
$ GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/home/qalexander/test-case-qalexander-2084b2876481.json
$ GCLOUD_PROJECT=test-case-qalexander
$ dotnet run
```

The variables were not exported and execution failed.

```
$ export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/home/qalexander/test-case-qalexander-2084b2876481.json
$ export GCLOUD_PROJECT=test-case-qalexander
$ dotnet run
```

Variables were exported and execution went successfully:

Check your that your variables are actually exported into environment. For Windows there are following commands [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples)] in section 3 subsection i:

## For this powershell session.

```
PS > $env:GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = "$env:USERPROFILE\Downloads\your-project-id-dea9fa230eae3.json"
```

## For all processes created after this command.

```
PS > [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", "$env:USERPROFILE\Downloads\your-project-id-dea9fa230eae3.json", "User")
```

In case this doesn’t help, please check your environment variables:

```
$ export #bash
```

Or for Windows:

```
PS> Get-ChildItem Env:
```